# Adding underbrace in the array environment to some arbitrary columns

Tags: arrays, braces, underbrace, overbrace

I've created the following output using the *array environment*, and I feel like it has to be created in that environment. As you can see, it's in three rows.

[image]
What I want, is to put the `\underbrace{}` in the exact same place as the following figure:

[image]

The LaTeX commands of the output is as the followings:

```
\[\begin{array}{ccccccccc}‎
‎‏‎\text{Saturday}‎ & ‎‏\text{Sunday} &‎ ‎‏\text{Mondey} &‎ ‎‏\text{Tuesday} &‎ ‎‏\text{Wednesday} ‎‎‏‏& &‎‎ ‎‏‎\text{Saturday} =‎ 4‎ &&‎ ‎‏\text{Wednesday} = 324  ‎‎‏\\
‎‏%‎\smash[b]{‎\underbrace{‎
x‎ & ‎3‎x & 9x & 27x & ‎81‎ x = ‎324‎
%}}‎
‎‎ & ‎‎\Longrightarrow& x ‎‎‎‎‎‎ = ‎4‎, && \text{Differenc‏e}‎ =‎ ‎320 ‎\\‎
‎‎\multicolumn{5}{c}{(0.75)} &‎ &‎ ‎(0.25) ‎&& ‎(0.25)‎
\end{array}\]‎‎‎‎
```

As you can see, I've commented out the `\smash[b]{‎\underbrace{‎}}` command, because leaving it enabled causes errors and the output completely clatters. Please help me on the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not done with `array`, but rather with stacks.  The intercolumn gap is adjusted with `\setstacktabbedgap{}` and the interrow baselineskip is adjusted with `\setstackgap{L}{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setstacktabbedgap{5pt}
\setstackgap{L}{18pt}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\savestack\leftside{\tabbedLongunderstack{
  Saturday & Sunday & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday\\
  $x$ & $3x$ & $9x$ & $27x$ & $81x = 324$
}}
\savestack\rightside{\tabbedLongunderstack{%
  & Saturday${}= 4$ && Wednesday${}=324$\\
  $\Longrightarrow$ & $x = 4$ && Difference ${}= 320$\\
  & (0.25) && (0.25)
}}
\tabbedLongunderstack{
  \stackunder[2\dimexpr\Lstackgap]{$\underbrace{\leftside}$}{(0.75)} & \rightside
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wants the brace lowered, a simple addition of `\addstackgap` remedies that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setstacktabbedgap{5pt}
\setstackgap{L}{18pt}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\savestack\leftside{\addstackgap[2pt]{\tabbedLongunderstack{
  Saturday & Sunday & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday\\
  $x$ & $3x$ & $9x$ & $27x$ & $81x = 324$
}}}
\savestack\rightside{\tabbedLongunderstack{%
  & Saturday${}= 4$ && Wednesday${}=324$\\
  $\Longrightarrow$ & $x = 4$ && Difference ${}= 320$\\
  & (0.25) && (0.25)
}}
\tabbedLongunderstack{
  \stackunder[2\dimexpr\Lstackgap]{$\underbrace{\leftside}$}{(0.75)} & \rightside
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just as a point of interest, I used `\tabbedLongunderstack{}` because all columns had identical (center) alignment.  There is also the `\tabularLongunderstack{<alignment>}{}` macro, if different columns required different alignments.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Why can't it be done with the array, is there any ways to do it with the array?

Comment: @Gahir Maybe someone can propose a solution with `array` and `\multicolumn`, but it's a joke around here that I will always redo things with stacks, since I wrote the `stackengine` and `tabstackengine` packages.  Reinventing the wheel and all that.  Glad I could be of some assistance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use two `tabular` environments aligned at the top, the first of which can be “underbraced” by reducing its dimensions.

The key is adding `\\[-\arraystretch\normalbaselineskip]` at the
end of the first tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
{\underbrace{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ccccc@{}}
Saturday & Sunday & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday \\
$x$      & $3x$   & $9x$   & $27x$   & $81x=324$ \\
\multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{$(0.75)$} \\[-\arraystretch\normalbaselineskip]
\end{tabular}}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}cc@{}}
                  & Saturday${}=4$  & Wednesday${}=324$ \\
$\Longrightarrow$ & $x=4$,          & Difference${}=320$ \\
                  & $(0.25)$        & $(0.25)$
\end{tabular}
\]    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spaces around `Longrightarrow` look not equal. Should be used `@{}` in the left second tabular also? I don't know.

Comment: Nice! A solution with `\Longrightarrow` between two `tabular` could be possible? Maybe could be hard to insert it exactly in the middle line.

Comment: @Sigur It is in the middle, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I was talking about the arrow not inside the tabular. When I see the output, first idea comes to my mind is 2 tabular and the arrow *in the middle*. Don't worry. Just offtopic. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

With trial and error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}%

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{*{9}{c}}‎
  ‎‏‎\text{Saturday}‎ & ‎‏\text{Sunday} &‎ ‎‏\text{Monday} &‎ ‎‏\text{Tuesday} &‎ ‎‏\text{Wednesday} ‎‎‏‏& &‎‎ ‎‏‎\text{Saturday} =‎ 4‎ &&‎ ‎‏\text{Wednesday} = 324 ‎‎‏\\
  x‎ & ‎3‎x & 9x & 27x & ‎81‎ x = ‎324‎
  ‎‎ & \Longrightarrow & x ‎‎‎‎‎‎ = ‎4‎, && \text{Differenc‏e}‎ =‎ ‎320 ‎\\
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\quad\;\raisebox{1.5ex}{$ \underbrace{\hspace{22em}}_{(0.75)} $}} &‎ &‎ ‎(0.25) ‎&& ‎(0.25)‎
  \end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to align all numbers in the last row, you can use the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, amsmath, makecell}
\usepackage{geometry}%

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{*{9}{c}}‎
  ‎‏‎\text{Saturday}‎ & ‎‏\text{Sunday} &‎ ‎‏\text{Monday} &‎ ‎‏\text{Tuesday} &‎ ‎‏\text{Wednesday} ‎‎‏‏& &‎‎ ‎‏‎\text{Saturday} =‎ 4‎ &&‎ ‎‏\text{Wednesday} = 324 ‎‎‏\\
  x‎ & ‎3‎x & 9x & 27x & ‎81‎ x = ‎324‎
  ‎‎ & =⇒ & x ‎‎‎‎‎‎ = ‎4‎, && \text{Differenc‏e}‎ =‎ ‎320 ‎\\[-1.5ex]
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\quad\;\makecell[bc]{\underbrace{\hspace{22em}}_{}\\[-1.5ex] (0.75)}} &‎ &‎ ‎(0.25) ‎&& ‎(0.25)‎
  \end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @gernot: I'll change that. My editor is configured for some ‘pretty printing’ and displays some symbols instead of the LaTeX code.

Comment: @Mico: I've added another solution to solve the problem you pointed.

Answer (score 3):

With tikz (needs two compilations):

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{*{9}{c}}
 \tikzmark{left}‏\text{Saturday} & ‏\text{Sunday} & ‏\text{Monday} & ‏\text{Tuesday} & ‏\text{Wednesday}\tikzmark{right} ‏‏& & ‏\text{Saturday} = 4 && ‏\text{Wednesday} = 324 ‏\\
  x & 3x & 9x & 27x & 81 x = 324
   & \Longrightarrow & x  = 4, && \text{Differenc‏e} = 320\tikzmark{row}\\[0.8\normalbaselineskip]
   \multicolumn{5}{c}{(0.75)} & & (0.25) && (0.25)
  \end{array}\]

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt,raise=2pt}]  ({pic cs:row} -| {pic cs:right}) -- ({pic cs:row} -| {pic cs:left});
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceArray}{*{9}{c}}
  \text{Saturday}& \text{Sunday} & \text{Mondey} & \text{Tuesday} & \text{Wednesday} & & \text{Saturday} = 4 && \text{Wednesday} = 324 \\
  x & 3x & 9x & 27x & 81 x = 324 & \Longrightarrow& x = 4, && \text{Difference} = 320 \\[2mm]
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{(0.75)} & & (0.25) && (0.25)
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[yshift=-2mm]{(2-1}{2-5}{}
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]